# mootools add an id

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there a method like toggleClass() for and ID in mootools?

Comment: Do you want to toggle the ID or toggle the class on an element you have the ID of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("someid").toggleClass("selectedState");` // add or take away .selectedState to an element

**but there is no native .toggleId, or am I not reading this question right**. As suggested, use .set("id") or code your own function. if your objective here is to have, say:

`formelement.getElement("input[type=submit]").toggleID("submitter");`

it can go like so:

```
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

...

```
Element.implement({
    toggleID: function(id) {
        return this.set("id", (this.get("id") == id) ? "" : id);
    }
});

var el = document.getElement("div.foo");

el.toggleID("foo");
alert(el.get("id")); // foo
el.toggleID("foo");
alert(el.get("id")); // null
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Element.set();` method.

`$('elementID').set('id', 'newId');`

documentation: [mootools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:set)

Comment: +1 - Factoring the title in this is probably what the OP wants, I was thrown by how such an unrelated method got into the question heh.